# How to specify axes when using the function `fit`

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-guide, multiple-axes

I have two axes: one for viewing images and the other for plotting graphs. I get this error when I try to specify which axes I want to plot the data on: `Error using plot. A numeric or double convertible argument is expected` when trying `plot(handles.axis,curve,x,y)`.

```
figure
handles.axis = gca;
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
curve = fit(x',y','linearinterp');
plot(curve,x,y) % works fine
plot(handles.axis,curve,x,y) % doesn't work
plot(curve,x,y,'Parent',handles.axis)  % doesn't work
```

You can paste this example into Matlab to try it out. How can the code be corrected in order to specify the axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plot` in the curve fitting toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/plot.html) is not the same as [MATLAB's base `plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). Though there is a documented syntax for specifying the parent axes for `sfit` objects, there doesn't seem to be one for `cfit` objects, which would be returned by your `fit` call in this case.

However, from the documentation we see that:

> `plot(cfit)` plots the `cfit` object over the domain of the current axes, if any

So if the [current axis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#prop_CurrentAxes) is set prior to the `plot` call it should work as desired. This can be done either by modifying the figure's `CurrentAxes` property or by calling [`axes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) with the handle of an axes object as an input.

```
% Set up GUI
h.f = figure;
h.ax(1) = axes('Parent', h.f, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.07 0.1 0.4 0.85]);
h.ax(2) = axes('Parent', h.f, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.55 0.1 0.4 0.85]);

% Set up curve fit
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
curve = fit(x', y', 'linearinterp');  % Returns cfit object

axes(h.ax(2));  % Set right axes as CurrentAxes
% h.f.CurrentAxes = h.ax(2);  % Set right axes as CurrentAxes
plot(curve, x, y);
```

Comment: Your solution looks exactly the same as the erroneous code from above. Can the axes even be specified if using the `plot` in the curve fitting toolbox?

Comment: @Senyokbalgul I have updated my response, I didn't notice that MATLAB made a distinction between plotting `sfit` and `cfit` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I refine my answer as follows:

It looks that the `plot` function in [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) does not like a fit object after an axis followed by two vectors. In such case, I would do something like this:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
figure % new figure
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);

curve = fit(x',y','linearinterp');
plot(ax1,x,curve(x));
hold on;plot(ax1,x,y,'o') % works fine

plot(ax2,x,curve(x));
hold on;plot(ax2,x,y,'o') % works fine
```

Actually the trick is to provide `x` and then `curve(x)` as two vectors without giving the whole fit-object to the `plot` function.